# request for member "..." in "..." which is of non-class type "..."

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I've been hunting around for hours trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong, and I've gotten rid of most of my problems but when I try to compile my code in `main()` it comes up with this same error message:

```
request for member "..." in "..." which is of non-class type "..."
```

and it repeats itself for all of the functions I try to call in `main()`. What is the problem? I can't figure out where my error is.

I'm using Terminal on a macbook to compile the code.

Here is my main function:

```
//Program1.cpp
//Program1Math test function
#include "Program1Math.h"

int main()
{
  //Create a Program1Math object
  Program1Math myProgram1Math();

  myProgram1Math.setNumber1();
  myProgram1Math.setNumber2();

  myProgram1Math.displayMultiple();
  myProgram1Math.displaySine1();
  myProgram1Math.displayTangent1();
  myProgram1Math.displaySine2();
  myProgram1Math.displayTangent2();
}
```

Here are the member-function definitions for the class:

```
//Program1Math.cpp
//Program1Math member-function definitions.
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include "Program1Math.h"
using namespace std;

//constructor makes a Program1Math, adds an blank line
Program1Math::Program1Math()
{
  cout << "/n";
}

//function to assign the first integer to its appropriate location
void Program1Math::setNumber1()
{
  cout << "Please enter the first integer number /n";
  int numberSpot;
  cin >>numberSpot;
  static_cast<double>(numberSpot);
  number1 = numberSpot;
}

//function to assign the second integer to its appropriate location
void Program1Math::setNumber2()
{
  cout << "Please enter the second integer number /n";
  int numberSpot;
  cin >>numberSpot;
  static_cast<double>(numberSpot);
  number2 = numberSpot;
}

//function to find the sine value for a specified number
void Program1Math::calculateSine( double inputNumber )
{
  sineValue = sin( inputNumber ); 
}

//function to find the tangent value for a specified number
void Program1Math::calculateTangent( double inputNumber )
{
  tangentValue = tan( inputNumber );
}

//function to determine if the user-inputted numbers are multiples of each other
void Program1Math::calculateModulus()
{
  int number1Int = static_cast<int>(number1);
  int number2Int = static_cast<int>(number2);
  int modulusValue = number1Int % number2Int;
  if ( modulusValue == 0 )
    multiple = true;
  else
    multiple = false;
}

//function to display the whether the numbers are multiples or not
void Program1Math::displayMultiple()
{
  if( multiple == true )
    cout<< number1 << " is a multiple of " << number2 << "!/n";
  else
    cout<< number1 << "is not a multiple of " << number2 << "./n";
}

//function to display the sine value of the first number
void Program1Math::displaySine1()
{
  calculateSine( number1 );
  cout << "Sine(" << number1 << ") = " << sineValue << "/n";
}

//function to display the sine value of the second number
void Program1Math::displaySine2()
{
  calculateSine( number2 );
  cout << "Sine(" << number2 << ") = " << sineValue << "/n";
}

//function to display the tangent value of the first number
void Program1Math::displayTangent1()
{
  calculateTangent( number1 );
  cout << "Tan(" << number1 << ") = " << tangentValue << "/n";
}

//function to display the tangent value of the second number
void Program1Math::displayTangent2()
{
  calculateTangent( number2 );
  cout << "Tan(" << number2 << ") = " << tangentValue << "/n";
}
```

here is the header file:

```
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

class Program1Math
{
 public:
  Program1Math();
  void setNumber1();
  void setNumber2();
  void calculateSine( double );
  void calculateTangent( double );
  void calculateModulus();
  void displayMultiple();
  void displaySine1();
  void displaySine2();
  void displayTangent1();
  void displayTangent2();
 private:
  double number1;
  double number2;
  double sineValue;
  double tangentValue;
  bool multiple;
};
```

Comment: I believe the answer my require the class declaration as well as the definition.

Comment: I don't thing this can be diagnosed this without the header file with the class definition.

Comment: Why are you inputting your numbers as ints and casting them to doubles?  Why not read them in directly as doubles?

Answer (score 18):

the line `Program1Math myProgram1Math();` is interpreted as a function declaration `myProgram1Math()` returning `Program1Math`;

Just use

```
 Program1Math myProgram1Math;
```

Only use () when a constructor accepts an parameter (without a default argument).

EDIT : you must compile all the source (.cpp) files that comprise your program.
That will produce object files of the same name with a different extension (on windows this is .obj ,for you it's .o).

After that all those `.o`-files must be linked togetcher with some compiler-provided libraries to make your executable program.

Comment: most vexing parse indeed

Comment: when I do that I get this error message:  Undefined symbols:
  "Program1Math::displaySine1()", referenced from:
      _main in ccIvBynB.o
  "Program1Math::displaySine2()", referenced from:
      _main in ccIvBynB.o
  "Program1Math::displayTangent1()", referenced from:
      _main in ccIvBynB.o
  "Program1Math::Program1Math()", referenced from:
      _main in ccIvBynB.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Those are linker errors telling you that you haven't provided an implementation for those member-functions

Comment: but I made the implementation in the Program1Math.cpp file I thought

Comment: Did you include Program1Math.cpp in your build ?

Comment: as in did I include the line #include "Program1Math.cpp" ?

Comment: Can you edit your Post and provide compiler and the way you compile and link

Comment: I'm using terminal to compile and I don't really know what I'm doing to link. This is the first time I've tried to write code for c++ or on a mac.

Comment: editted my answer. Does this help a bit ?

Comment: I think so. I will try to link them, but I'm seriously handicapped by ignorance here.

Comment: Every programmer went through this learning curve! Don't be embaressed.

Comment: I think I'm linking correctly, but I get the message         Undefined symbols:
  "Program1Math::Program1Math()", referenced from:
      _main in ccFM1KZu.o
I feel like there is something fundamentally incorrect with some bit of this but I can't step back enough to see what

Comment: If your sur that you linked Program1.o and Program1Math.o then there is something weird going on. My knowledge for that falls short. Maybe make it a sepate question.

Comment: @user596228: it's 4.00 AM here. Going to sleep. Hope you'll will succeed.

Comment: thank you! I will ask the professor tomorrow afternoon, maybe he will have some pointers. I appreciate the advice and encouragement!

Answer (score 1):

You should create the `Program1Math` instance like this:

```
Program1Math myProgram1Math;
```

or to allocate the object on the heap, use the `new` keyword:

```
Program1Math *myProgram1Math = new Program1Math();
```

Comment: I didn't think I could use "= new" in c++. Isn't that for Java?

Comment: -1: That is Java-syntax. In C++ the 'new' is not correct in this case.

Comment: @Sjoerd, Indeed, in C++ new returns a pointer and allocates memory on the heap. Answer edited for correctness.

Comment: @user596228, `new` is a perfectly valid operator in C++ (not C). The main difference from garbage-collecting Java is that you have to explicitly free the allocated memory using `delete myProgram1Math;` somewhere later, or you'll get a memory leak. That's why it is usually better to just declare a local variable, like you do in your code. `new` is usually only required if you want your object to continue to exist after the function returns (but you must store the pointer somewhere before it does, or you won't be able to use it or free it - memory leak once more).